# Is it possible to iterate through pair of values using for loop in c++?

Tags: c++, vector

Is something like this is possible or there is any way to assign the pair values separately in `for` loop?

```cpp
vector<pair<int, int>> arr;
// Input some values here in arr
for(auto &[x,y]: arr){
     cout<<x<<" "<<y;
}
```

Comment: Your code [compiles](https://wandbox.org/permlink/g3SVc9AcrJQtQ7GM) as C++17.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This uses structured bindings: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding . It should compile in C++17.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks. I got it. I have seen like this in someone else's code but in my version it was getting me error. Now I have to change to C++17.

Comment: @MikeCAT Add answer?

Comment: @Anonymous1847 I won't because I don't know C++17 and I just found this by seeing compiler message. You can add answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is actually valid code in C++17 or later, as @MikeCAT said. You're using what's called a [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding). It can unpack values from arrays or simple class types, in this case from `pair`s.